# aspCode runner generates which syntax of CODE?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

i'm using ASP RUNNER software to generate auto code, it generates this code

```
Function employeeRecord_Snippet1()
Response.Write "Your message"
End Function ' employeeRecord_Snippet1
```

now i don't understand that is it ASP.net code or ASP code ?

Comment: It looks like Classic ASP.  What are your file extensions, .asp or .aspx

Answer (score 1):

From the product homepage

"ASPRunnerPro creates professionally looking **classic ASP applications** enabling users to search, edit, delete and add data to the Oracle, SQL Server, MS Access, DB2, or MySQL databases."

http://xlinesoft.com/asprunnerpro/